# ScriptRunner Merge Check for Bitbucket Get Associated Jira Issue

Tags: groovy, bitbucket, jira, jira-rest-api, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I would like to set up a Merge Check that will block a merge if the associated Jira Issue has any blocking tasks.

I have searched for the solution before coming here and found [the following example](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Scriptrunner-Validator-for-quot-is-blocked-by-quot-linked-issue/qaq-p/1142408). However, right at `import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor` I get an "unable to resolve class" error. I am running the latest version of Scriptrunner for Bitbucket Server v.7.10.0.

I have attempted to use AppLinks as shown in [the following example](https://docs.adaptavist.com/sr4bib/latest/atlassian-integrations/connect-via-app-links) and see that I am able to access the Jira Api this way, however I am unsure of how to actually determine the Task Id of the issue linked to the triggering Merge Branch.

I am having a hard time finding any up to date documentation that doesn't involve random Adaptavist or Atlasian forumn posts. Does anyone have any insight for how I can get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ComponentAccessor is no longer supported, and my non-descript errors were a result of lower permissions. Once being promoted to admin I was able to access the Script Editor window which allowed me to perform the following...

To replace the provided ["Is Blocked on Jira" example](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Scriptrunner-Validator-for-quot-is-blocked-by-quot-linked-issue/qaq-p/1142408) I instead created a Jira Issue Controller class that is responsible for accessing the information using appLinks and Jira API calls.

```
import com.atlassian.applinks.api.ApplicationLinkResponseHandler
import com.atlassian.applinks.api.ApplicationLinkService
import com.atlassian.applinks.api.application.jira.JiraApplicationType
import com.atlassian.sal.api.component.ComponentLocator
import com.atlassian.sal.api.net.Response
import com.atlassian.sal.api.net.ResponseException
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
 
import static com.atlassian.sal.api.net.Request.MethodType.GET

// This class is responsiblefor retrieving specific issues from the JiraAppLink (api)
class IssueController{
    private static String issueEndpoint = "/rest/api/2/issue/"

    // doc - https://docs.atlassian.com/applinks-api/3.2/com/atlassian/applinks/api/ApplicationLinkResponseHandler.html
    private static ApplicationLinkResponseHandler<Map> handler = new ApplicationLinkResponseHandler<Map>() { 
        // Triggered when a call to a remote server failed because the caller does not have an established session 
        // with the server and will need to authorize requests first by visiting the authorization URL provided by 
        // AuthorisationURIGenerator.
        @Override
        Map credentialsRequired(Response response) throws ResponseException {
            return null
        }
    
        @Override
        Map handle(Response response) throws ResponseException {
            assert response.statusCode == 200
            new JsonSlurper().parseText(response.getResponseBodyAsString()) as Map
        }
    }

    static RestObjects.JiraIssue GetJiraIssue(String issueKey){
        def appLinkService = ComponentLocator.getComponent(ApplicationLinkService)
        def appLink = appLinkService.getPrimaryApplicationLink(JiraApplicationType)
        def appLinkUrl = appLink.getDisplayUrl().toString()
        // doc - https://docs.atlassian.com/applinks-api/3.2/com/atlassian/applinks/api/ApplicationLinkRequestFactory.html
        def applicationLinkRequestFactory = appLink.createAuthenticatedRequestFactory()
        // doc - https://docs.atlassian.com/applinks-api/3.2/com/atlassian/applinks/api/ApplicationLinkRequest.html
        def linkRequest = applicationLinkRequestFactory.createRequest(GET, issueEndpoint + issueKey )
        def response = linkRequest.execute(handler)
        return new RestObjects.JiraIssue(response);
    }
}
```

This class returns a custom object `RestObjects.JiraIssue` I use to parse the specific API response Map into custom Classes. A short example of the JiraIssue class and how I am able to access the linked blocking issues is shown below.

```
package JiraApp.RestObjects

class JiraIssue
{
    String key
    Fields fields

    //public
    JiraIssue(keyStr){
        this.key = keyStr
    }
    JiraIssue(Map apiResponseMap)
    {
        this.key = apiResponseMap["key"]
        this.fields = new Fields(apiResponseMap["fields"] as Map)
    }

    //Returns list of the keys linked blocking issues 
    String[] blockingIssueKeys(){
        String[] keys = []
        fields.issueLinks.each { 
            link -> 
                if(link.type.name == "Blocks" && link.getInwardIssue() != null)
                {
                    def inwardIssue = link.getInwardIssue()
                    keys += inwardIssue.key
                }
        }
        return keys;
    }

    class Fields{
        Fields(Map fieldsMap){.....
```

The rest of this class uses nested classes to parse the input Maps for their fields into usable objects. It also contains objects/functions I have created for my specific application.

I hope this answer is helpful to someone, the documentation on ScriptRunner for bitbucket is limited.